# Get Value Method In Mulesoft Studio

Tags: web-services, mule, anypoint-studio

I built an app to generate a web service.
This is the design of the app.

[image]

I tried to get a return value from a java class.

This is the java class

```
public int setTotalValue(){
    int a, b,c;
    FWService fwService = new FWService();
    FWebService fWebService = fwService.getFWebServicePort();
    SWService swService = new SWService();
    SWebService sWebService = swService.getSWebServicePort();
    TWService twService = new TWService();
    TWebService tWebService = twService.getTWebServicePort();

    a = fWebService.getValue();
    b = sWebService.getValue();
    c = tWebService.setTotalValue(a, b);
    System.out.println("Result :: "+c);

    return c;
}
```

When I run the app, http://localhost:8081/resultwebservice,
the result is
"No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown."

Answer (score 0):

To invoke java class,

1. Create bean for your java class.
2. Use that bean name as object-ref in java component & mention the method name.

   ```
   package invoke;
   public class GreetingService {

    public String sayHello(String name) {
      return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }

    public String sayGoodbye(String name) {
      return String.format("Goodbye %s!", name);
    }
   }
   ```

   **Mule flow:**

   ```
   <spring:beans>
    <spring:bean name="greetingService" class="invoke.GreetingService"/>
   </spring:beans>
   <http:listener-config name="listener-config" host="localhost"  port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
   <flow name="greetingFlow" >
    <http:listener config-ref="listener-config" path="greeting" doc:name="HTTP Connector"/>
    <invoke object-ref="greetingService" method="sayHello" methodArguments="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]" doc:name="Invoke"/>
   </flow>
   ```